# How to retrieve a database model for Entity Framework Core with ValueConversions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

I've got an asp.net core web api project, where I use Entity Framework. I take in a DTO from the web and convert (using AutoMapper) to a database entity.

At this point I could do some post processing of the entity on the server, before it hits the database. Because of the database structure and limitations in Entity Framework, I need to pass this entity to a stored procedure. At this point I want to get the database model WITH conversions applied.

Basically, this flow...

Controller takes in DTO -> AutoMapper to Entity -> allows me to work with objects and do things before saving -> Save, but using a stored procedure.

My model has a conversion, so how do I get the representation I want for the database at the point where I perform the query?

The problem is I get "false" as a parameter in the controller, this gets converted to a boolean in the entity model, this gets converted to a string ("false") when I want to save it, how do I apply the conversion defined in the entity framework model so that I can save "Y" or "N" as expected?

Simplified example below...

To clarify the question, I need to be able to get the database representation of the model before calling the stored proc, with the code I have below, ToString will be called, so I will get "false" not "N". I have a way to do this when retrieving data, using ValueConversions (that is database -> model). If I was using SaveChanges, EF Core would take care of the conversion (model -> database), but when using raw SQL (in the case a stored proc), how do I get the database representation. At this point, if my model has a boolean property, I want to pass "Y" or "N" to the raw SQL as a parameter... does that make it clearer?

```
public class TodoDto
{
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public long Id{ get; set; }

    public string Item { get; set; }

    public bool Done { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateStamp { get; set; }
    // other properties, model is more complex, but removed to keep it simple
}

public class TodoEFCoreModel
{
    [Column("TodoId"), ReadOnly(true)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Column("TodoItem")]
    public string Item { get; set; }

    public bool? Done { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateStamp { get; set; }
    // other properties
}    

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    var yesNoConversion = new YesNoToBoolConverter();

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<TodoEFCoreModel>()
        .Property(x => x.Done)
        .HasConversion(yesNoConversion);
}

public ActionResult PostToDo(TodoDto todo)
{
    // code is then roughly
    var databaseTodoEntity = _mapper.Map<TodoDto, TodoEFCoreModel>(todo);

    // here I can check databaseTodoEntity boolean property
    // and/or manipulate the model

    // when it comes to saving I need to use a stored procedure, I can do this using ExecuteSqlCommandAsync...
    await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("begin CreateTodo(Item => :p0, Done => :p1, DateStamp => :p2); end;", parameters: new[]
        {
            new OracleParameter("p0", OracleDbType.VarChar2, databaseTodoEntity.Item, ParameterDirection.Input),

            // The problem is here, with this code I get "false", instead of the conversion that Entity Framework would apply if I were to be able to call "SaveChanges" on the db context...
            new OracleParameter("p1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, databaseTodoEntity.Done, ParameterDirection.Input),

            new OracleParameter("p2", OracleDbType.Date, databaseTodoEntity.DateStamp, ParameterDirection.Input)
        });
}
```

Comment: Why bother with two mappings? It's confusing. Just do everything with AM. Or EF converters if you prefer.

Comment: Use this AutoMapper config to map your bool from/to string Y/N: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616296/automapper-true-false-to-y-n-and-reverse

Comment: Alternatively, add a property to your model to handle the conversion: `public string DoneString { get { return Done.HasValue? Done.Value? "Y" : "N" : string.Empty; } }`

Comment: Just to clarify, EF configuration is for EF generated SQL and will not apply to raw SQL like your case. You will have to use something custom for that.

Comment: @jcruz - yes, looking for a good custom way to do that... my model has a load of properties, I was hoping there would be something in EF Core that I could hook into to say, give me the translated SQL value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core internally uses [RelationalTypeMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.relationaltypemapping?view=efcore-2.1) class instances which

> Represents the mapping between a .NET type and a database type.

and for specific entity property can be obtained with [FindRelationalMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.internal.relationalpropertyextensions.findrelationalmapping?view=efcore-2.1) extension method.

Note that this method is considered part of the "internal" API, so you need

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;
```

and be ok with the typical warning

> This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.

Now, along with the [`Converter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.coretypemapping.converter?view=efcore-2.1) and other useful properties, you'd also get an access to some useful methods like [CreateParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.relationaltypemapping.createparameter?view=efcore-2.1), which can be used directly in your scenario. It will do all the necessary conversions and parameter preparation as with EF Core generated commands.

For instance:

```
var sql = "begin CreateTodo(Item => :p0, Done => :p1, DateStamp => :p2); end;";
var entityType = _dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TodoEFCoreModel));
var dbCommand = _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
object[] parameters =
{
    entityType.FindProperty("Item").FindRelationalMapping()
        .CreateParameter(dbCommand, "p0", databaseTodoEntity.Item),
    entityType.FindProperty("Done").FindRelationalMapping()
        .CreateParameter(dbCommand, "p1", databaseTodoEntity.Done),
    entityType.FindProperty("DateStamp").FindRelationalMapping()
        .CreateParameter(dbCommand, "p2", databaseTodoEntity.DateStamp),
};
await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sql, parameters);
```

Note that `DbCommand` instance is used only as `DbParameter` factory (`DbCommand.CreateParameter`). The created parameters are not added to that command, so it can safely be discarded afterwards.

Comment: This is insanely good! Thank you! Exactly what I needed.

Should someone just need the conversion value, rather than the created parameter, you can look at 

.FindRelationalMapping().Converter.ConvertToProvider(todo.Done);

... but I'll be using everything in the example - Thanks again!